# Delete TFS Multiple workspaces at once

Tags: powershell, tfs

I need to create a schedule task, for deleting TFS workspaces which are older than 3days. 
Please suggest the command or powershell script i can use

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is not a code-writing service.

Answer (score 1):

Workspace doesn't have a creation time, so it's not able to find out the workspaces which are older than 3 days. You can only achieve deleting workspace with [Workspace Command](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tfvc/workspace-command):

```
tf workspace /delete [/collection:TeamProjectCollectionUrl] workspacename[;workspaceowner][/login:username,[password]]
```

You can also run the TF.exe program with the necessary arguments in PowerShell script:

```
& "$env:C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\TF.exe" @("workspace", "/delete", "/collection:TeamProjectCollectionUrl", "workspacename")
```